# AngularJS parent div directive wait for children div stacked directives to complete

Tags: angularjs

I have a portion of html that is like this

```
<div my-custom-security-directive>
  <button ng-if={{some constraints}} ng-click={{logic}}>cancel</button>
  <button ng-disabled={{some logic}} ng-click={{some logic}}>submit<button>
</div>
```

My custom security directive does dom manipulation to the buttons to show/hide them via css. The issue I am having is with timing and perhaps directive precedence? When all the code is finished executing I only see the submit button and not the cancel button. I believe this is because of the ng-if and I attempted to set the priority of my custom directive to a negative number to run last but I think that is only for stacked directives on the same element? I only have a `link` function defined in my directive which my understanding is that is the same as a `post link` function and should run once the children complete?  Ultimately, my goal is to run my directive 'last' so that I can show both buttons if all the logic in the directive passes.

The shell of my directive :

```
angular.module('myModule')
.directive("myCustomSecurityDirective", function(a,b) {
    //
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        priority: -1,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            //custom security role/perm logic using injected services a&b etc
                if (userHasPermission ) {
                    element.find('input, textarea, button').addClass('my-show-css');

                }

        }
    };
});
```

I did recently /today put that priority on the directive but I don't think it does anything in this particular scenario.

Comment: Does `my-custom-security-directive` use transclusion? Showing some more code could help.

Comment: no transclusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if `my-custom-security-directive` is able to attach a CSS class to the button and hide or show it, the button has its own `ng-if` condition. This means it's possible that the button could be destroyed and recreated later, and it wouldn't have the CSS class anymore. If the button uses `ng-show` instead of `ng-if` you may have more control, since the button would become hidden but remain in the DOM.

But I think `my-custom-security-directive` might want to have more control. You can use transclusion so that `my-custom-security-directive` acts as a container for each set of elements which should be destroyed or created based on `userHasPermission`.

Directive:

```
.directive('myCustomSecurityDirective', function () {
    return {
        transclude: true,
        link: function (scope) {
            scope.userHasPermission = true;
        },
        template: '<div ng-if="userHasPermission" ng-transclude></div>'
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div my-custom-security-directive>
    <button ng-if="...">cancel</button>
    <button ng-disabled="...">submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I opted against transclusion only because this directive is re-used all over the place and it doesn't always 'contain' this problematic div. Your answer is valid and I came to the conclusion I was in a tough place in terms of things I could do: transclude/ custom or one -off version of directive. I ended up leaving this as is to keep the directive simpler and added the necessary classes to that problem div because it will get removed by `ng-if` if it doesn't meet requirements. I don't really love my solution but I think it was the simplest for this app.